# How to retrieve value of start date with format end date?

Tags: 8, datetime

I D8 installed the module [Optional End Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/optional_end_date) in order to add an optional end date within a date field.

When I had a single date field value I could get the value by using:

```
 $datum_deelname = $node->get('field_normaldate')->value;
```

If I change this in the new field name:

```
 $datum_deelname = $node->get('field_optional_enddate')->value;
```

I get back NULL.

How should I get this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
 $datum_deelname = $node->get('field_optional_enddate')->end_value;
```

This will give the `optional end date`.

If you want to get the normal date as you mentioned you can use as:

```
 $datum_deelname = $node->get('field_optional_enddate')->value;
```